# Angular Material styles of subcomponent not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

An angular 7 project with an installed @angular/material 7 npm package and included theme reference, material icons link in app.component.html, etc. is rendering all material components in the root app.component.html but seems to be improperly rendering material components from all other modules.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Tried different modules - affecting all other modules other than
   root.
2. Tried to recompile and re ng serve - same thing.
3. Tried various components, all are improperly rendered.

The issue persists... Any help thinking about this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

It turns out, as instructed in angular material's docs, that one theme must be referenced in the project. For example:

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink";

The problem was that the import statement was included initially in app.component.scss whereas it should have been in the root styles.scss file!